# Reading JSON using Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong - can't access "links" on my JSON file.

Part of code (MainActivity.kt):

```
var arr = arrayListOf<String>()

fun read_json() {
        var json : String? = null

        try {
            val inputStream:InputStream = assets.open("links.json")
            json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}

            var jsonarr = JSONArray(json)

            for (i in 0..jsonarr.length()-1){
                var jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i)
                arr.add(jsonobj.getString("links"))
            }

            var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr)
            json_list.adapter = adapter
        }
        catch(e : IOException){

        }
    }
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "links": 
  [
    "google.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "facebook.com"
  ]
}
```

If I remake JSON file, so it will like in the following JSON file, everything works fine. However, I need to use the previous file.

```
[
 {
   "links": "google.com"
 }
]
```

Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to get the JSON array first and read strings from it, something like this:

```
var jsonarr = JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("links")

for (i in 0..jsonarr.length()-1) {
    arr.add(jsonarr.getString(i))
}
```

Comment: But I can use getJSONObject only after I declare variable jsonarr to JASONArray. Or am I doing something wrong in this situation?

Comment: Indeed, you would need to parse the json string into an object prior to accessing the array. I fixed the example.